# How to fix this turtle function?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I run into an error with this problem I have. I need to write a function called droplets that
draw a series of droplets. The parameters are t for turtle to draw the droplets, size (diameter of each droplet), and separations (which is a list and it is used for the distance between each droplet). I use Python version 3.4.2. The error I am getting is a TypeError. Here is the code:

```
def droplets(t, size, separations):
    for i in range(len(separations)):
        t.down()
        t.circle(size)
        t.up()
        t.forward([separations * i])

import turtle
turt = turtle.Turtle()
droplets(turt, 5, [20, 25, 30])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/My Python Program/Midterm 2 PP Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    droplets(turt, 5, [20, 25, 30])
  File "C:/Python34/My Python Program/Midterm 2 PP Test.py", line 6, in droplets
    t.forward([separations * i])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\turtle.py", line 1636, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\turtle.py", line 1603, in _go
    ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
  File "C:\Python34\lib\turtle.py", line 257, in __mul__
    return Vec2D(self[0]*other, self[1]*other)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over `separations`:

```
def droplets(t, size, separations):
    for i in range(len(separations)):
        t.down()
        t.circle(size)
        t.up()
        t.forward(separations[i])
```

Or, more simply, just iterate over `separations` instead of using indexes:

```
def droplets(t, size, separations):
    for separation in separations:
        t.down()
        t.circle(size)
        t.up()
        t.forward(separation)
```